# Extracting Year from Date for ggplot2 to compare time series

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have the below data which I am trying to plot on the one chart so I can compare 2013 to 2014 data, with colour set by the 'year'.

I would like the output to look something like [this](http://janabeck.com/images/R/daily_mean_compare_years.png):
[image: plot example]

My example CSV data looks like the below:

```
Date        Data
1/01/2013   10
1/02/2013   20
1/03/2013   30
1/04/2013   20
1/01/2014   40
1/02/2014   70
1/03/2014   80
1/04/2014   90
```

I have the below code, but it doesn't extract the 'year' from the 'Date' data. I only know how to treat each 'date' with a different colour instead, but it's not really what I want.

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), y=Data,
            group=Date, color=Date)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
scale_color_discrete(name="Year") +
labs(x="",y="Test Data") +
geom_smooth(aes(group=1))
p
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra column `Year` to your data frame. Here is a simple example:

```
# create example data set
library("zoo")
library("strucchange")
d <- data.frame(Date=index(SP2001)+90, Data=SP2001$AAPL)
# add year column to data frame
d$Year <- format(d$Date, "%Y")

library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), y=Data,
            group=Year)) +
     geom_bar(aes(fill=Year), stat="identity") +
     labs(x="", y="Test Data") +
     geom_smooth(aes(colour=Year))
p
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

given a date object you can extract the year as follows
format(date_series,'%Y')

%Y will use 4 digits, %y just the last 2
you can add more elements to the format string, for example %Y%m outputs things like 201401, 201402 - I use this one frequently

Comment: That's great, thanks guys.

I just slightly modified the code because my dates got mucked up a bit, but the below works perfect:


    d$Date <- as.Date(d$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    d$Year <- format(d$Date, "%Y")

#Histogram
    p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=Date, y=Data, group=Year)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=Year),stat="identity") +
    labs(x="",y="Test Data") +
    geom_smooth(aes(colour=Year))

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format my response better